# cordova installing barcode plugin give an error git command line

Tags: git, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework to create an apps, and when trying to add the camera plugin in cmd.

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git
```

This gave an error

```
Fetching plugin "https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git" via
git clone Error: "git" command line tool is not installed: make sure
it is accessible on your PATH. at Object.clone
(C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\gitclone.js:35:25)
```

Trying to set the environment path to `C:\Program Files\git\bin` does not solve the problem, reinstalling the git does not solve the problem as well.

I am using 64Bit Windows 10, any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-install git and it will fix the problem.

https://git-scm.com/download/win

Is as simple as that

Comment: try to reinstall git, but does not help, end up uninstalling the node js and git, and reinstalling and worked